# Rendering Issue with LWC for nested components for nested components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am facing issue with LWC child component rendering which is nested in parent .

Description :
I am building some sort of burger builder app in salesforce LWC and component nesting is like below 
burgerbuilder > burger > burgeringredient

and I have standalone component with below nesting 
buildcontrols >buildcontrol

**buildcontrol** is basically if we want to add new ingredients then it will publish event and would be subscribed by **burgerbuilder** to add ingredients .

Issue : When I click on More button even though in buildcontrols js file the value is increasing for ingredient but its not reflecting on UI its not getting rendered .

I have uploaded the file in below link

[Code Link](https://github.com/rajeshkumar15191/lwcburgerbuilder)

Comment: I haven't looked far into the code but noticed the ingredient has a tracked property called "default" which is actually a keyword. This might cause issues...

Comment: Not sure where you are referring to but as per burger builder component below is the tracked property  @track ingredients = 
    {
            salad : 0,
            bacon: 0,
            cheese:0,
            meat:0
        }

Comment: "burgeringredient.js"

Comment: Thats is just a child component if you look at main is burgerbuilder component there ingredient is used and in burgeringredient api property 'type' is used .